# Multiple conditions formula for conditional formatting (OUT OF MY ELEMENT HERE)

Tags: excel

I'm a Registered Nurse and very out of my element here and just wanting a little help.
I want to create a conditional formatting formula to highlight the entire row if there is text in cell J7 but not in K7.

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywC99.png)

Comment: `=AND($J7<>"",$K7="")`

Comment: Thank you so much.